# Injecting $state object into factory object resulting in error

Tags: angularjs

When I am injecting $state service into my factory below, Angular returns a error. The error doesn't say much. However when i remove $state, the error is gone. What is happening ?

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.factory('AuthInterceptor',  function ($window, $q, $state) {
    return {

        request: function (config) {
            if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response['status'] >= 400) {
                console.log("Not Authorized.kindly login first");
                // $state.transitionTo('login');   
            }
            return response || $q.when(err);
        }
    };
} ])
```

Comment: Can you show what the error is?

Comment: @runtimeZero, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Argument do no match in your declaration for factory and hence the `$state` is not injected.

`.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$window', '$q', function ($window, $q, $state) {`

It should be

`.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$window', '$q','state', function ($window, $q, $state) {`